# Setting private property on ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have followed this tutorial for creating drop downs in ASP.NET MVC: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

The code sample given is:

```
public class IceCreamFlavor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly List<IceCreamFlavor> _flavors;

    [Display(Name = "Favorite Flavor")]
    public int SelectedFlavorId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FlavorItems
    {
        get { return new SelectList(_flavors, "Id", "Name");}
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to set `_flavors`?  It is `private readonly`.  Is there any reason for this?  Some feature of MVC to populate it?

I can obviously make it public or private with a constructor but I am wondering why Scott Allen set it this way.  Is there some logic to it?

Comment: As shown, no, you can't set it in any fashion. I would assume something was left out, since the only way I see to set that is via a constructor, which you don't have here.

Comment: Can you set readonly with a contructor?

Comment: It would be the only place you can set it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: @Tieson or you can make it field initializer  and initialize it at declaration I guess

Comment: This can never work. Your view model would need a constructor containing a parameter for `List<IceCreamFlavor>` but because the `DefaultModelBinder` can only initialize models that have a default constructor, it means that when you submit the data, the `FlavorItems` will always be `null` and cannot be populated, so if `ModelState` was invalid, you could never return the view to make corrections (it would throw an exception). Your view model should simply contain a property `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FlavorItems { get; set; }` which is set in the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the proper way to set _flavors?

You can set it to any `List<IceCreamFlavor>` you want based on your custom logic in the constructor of the view model.

The `readonly` modifier means that any assignments to the field must occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx.

So you cannot set this field from anywhere else than in the constructor of the `ViewModel` class. The part of initializing the list has obviously been omitted from the example (*"assuming the `_flavors` field is populated with real ice cream flavors from a database or elsewhere"*) but the view model class is supposed to create the `List<IceCreamFlavor>` in its constructor and then simply expose an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that the view can bind to. The outside world only knows about the *IEnumerable* . Only the view model class itself knows about the private `_flavors` field.